# PHP get_browser() returns strange values

Tags: php, browser

i want to use:

```
public function BrowserCheck() {
        static $Browser;
        if(!isset($Browser)){
            $Browser = get_browser($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],true);
        }
        return $Browser;
}
```

as suggested on http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php, but somehow var_dump($Result); will only output strange values:

```
array(30) {
["browser_name_regex"]=>
string(6) "§^.*$§"
["browser_name_pattern"]=>
string(1) "*"
["browser"]=>
string(15) "Default Browser"
["version"]=>
string(1) "0"
["majorver"]=>
string(1) "0"
["minorver"]=>
string(1) "0"
["platform"]=>
string(7) "unknown"
["alpha"]=>
string(0) ""
["beta"]=>
string(0) ""
["win16"]=>
string(0) ""
["win32"]=>
string(0) ""
["win64"]=>
string(0) ""
["frames"]=>
string(1) "1"
["iframes"]=>
string(0) ""
["tables"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cookies"]=>
string(0) ""
["backgroundsounds"]=>
string(0) ""
["cdf"]=>
string(0) ""
["vbscript"]=>
string(0) ""
["javaapplets"]=>
string(0) ""
["javascript"]=>
string(0) ""
["activexcontrols"]=>
string(0) ""
["isbanned"]=>
string(0) ""
["ismobiledevice"]=>
string(0) ""
["issyndicationreader"]=>
string(0) ""
["crawler"]=>
string(0) ""
["cssversion"]=>
string(1) "0"
["supportscss"]=>
string(0) ""
["aol"]=>
string(0) ""
["aolversion"]=>
string(1) "0"
}
```

Why? I am using Chrome and it only gives me back some "§^.*$§" as found name? That can't be true... What is wrong here?

Comment: what is `$Result`? It's not mentioned in code above

Comment: Did you read the browscap note in the bottom: http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php#refsect1-function.get-browser-notes the browscap ini settings requires a source to identify the browser; without it there's no guarantee the browser will be identified. Also see related question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003228/get-browser-not-working?rq=1

Comment: also, do note that `get_browser()` depends on a well formatted user agent. Try printing out to see that it is correctly reported by your server.

Comment: Enable browscap in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

This function uses information from the browscap.ini file. This is maybe not the best solution because the file could not be up to date all the time. Try to get just the user agent and determine via regular expression the name.

Answer (score 0):

You forget about: http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/  -- download version for PHP ! and rename from php_browscap.ini to browscap.ini

Comment: I did this already... Even the newest browscap.ini didn't give me any other result.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function BrowserCheck() {
        static $Browser;
        if(!isset($Browser)){
            $Browser = $browser = get_browser(null, true);
        }
        return $Browser;
}
```

Don't use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. get_browser function will return the information of browser by default.

Try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function BrowserCheck() {
        static $Browser;
        if(!isset($Browser)){
            //You can bypass $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] parameter with a NULL value. 
            //you will get right result.  
            $Browser = $browser = get_browser(null, true);
        }
        return $Browser;
}

Try this code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check browscap is enabled in your php.ini,If not enable it and restart appache

```
 [browscap]
 ; http://php.net/browscap
 browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

If it is already exist,Please check "browscap.ini" is exist in the location,If it is not exist

[browscap.ini](http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/)

Download,And add to the path

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem, if you're using Xampp or Wamp server on Windows, then this is the solution.

1. Download the latest file `full_php_browser.ini`(38 MB) from [Browscap](http://browscap.org/).
2. Then change the name to `browscap.ini` and put it into `C:\xampp\php\extras\`.
3. Open `php.ini` and add this -

   ```
   [browscap]
   ;http://php.net/browscap
   browscap = "C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
   ```

And it will definitely work.