# get_browser() in PHP only works with IE

Tags: php

I use this function in my code. And it works with only IE. It is not working with Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. In these browsers it returns the browser name as "Default Browser" and OS name as "unknown".

Why this is happening tho these browsers and works fine with IE?

I'm using IE8, Firefox 30 and Chrome 35.

Thank You.

Comment: [Update your `browscap.ini` file](http://browscap.org/), dont know what that is then [read the manual notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#refsect1-function.get-browser-notes)

Comment: Do you have a correct browscap.ini?

Comment: What code are you running exactly? Have you looked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003228/get-browser-not-working

Comment: it works after downloading latest browsecap.ini
Thanks guys..