# I'm trying to store User Browser details in the database-

Tags: php, browser

In PHP is there any way to store user's browser details?? The reason for this is that I want to analyse all the unique devices the user is using his/her login credentials from. By browser details I mean if there is any sort of unique code a browser has that I can store to identify whether the logged in device is new or an existing one. I've already used get_browser(), it's returning the browser versions and I don't understand how to use it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

This returns an string

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
```

**OPTION 2**

This will return an array of details.
You can try this function, then you can store this details to your database.
if this doesnt work. try reading this [get_browser not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003228/get-browser-not-working)

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
```

The above example will **output** something similar to:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

you can check docs here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: hey @jenuel I tried the above code but there seem to be some issue on my system/server that causing the get_browser function not returning any data.

Comment: your can try reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003228/get-browser-not-working or use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] instead

Comment: Yeah I will check it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is it.

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although I tried the above code but get_browser doesn't seem to work on my system. wondering why..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but people are missing few new things, so I think there is no harm to share it :-)

Please also try:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM']; // Windows or Android etc.
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA']; // web browser necessary details
```

The above variables output necessary and to the point information on most CPanel and other web servers these days.